# Method similar to executeUpdate after using persist() in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Is there any method which returns the numbers of rows affected by the `entityManager.persist()` method? I'm trying to migrate a system which uses pure JDBC to JPA.

Comment: How are you updating the rows? If you are using a query, then you are probably going to use the `executeUpdate` itself. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: I'm not using a query, that's the problem.


...
ClientEntity.setObs(client.getObs());
ClientEntity.setForm(client.getForm());

entitymanager.persist(ClientEntity);
entitymanager.flush();
System.out.println(ClientEntity.getId());

Comment: Isn't ClientEntity mapped to a database table? When `persist` is called, it takes the `ClientEntity` instance and persists it to the mapped table as a single row. It cannot affect multiple rows. May be, tell us what is that you are trying to do - this could be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)